# Is there a term to describe a function that strictly increases to a maximum and then strictly decreases thereafter? (Or vice versa)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Answer wouldn't be a parabola since it's not necessarily symmetric.

Skewed bell curves would all fit this criteria but the function I want to refer to isn't a distribution, so I'm looking for a better term.

Comment: Perhaps concave?

Comment: They are sometimes called (strongly) [unimodal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality#Unimodal_function).

Comment: @jlammy That's not quite right. Concavity says the first derivative is decreasing; this condition says something a bit stronger, namely that the first derivative is strictly decreasing _and_ admits a zero.